# Dynamically modifying the DOM in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm running Angular Version 6 -- I'm trying to perform functionality in Angular that is fairly trivial in vanilla JavaScript.

*this.value* is the value of a search from an input element, *places* is an array with city and state properties -- the goal is to highlight the text being searched on each result in a list of results.

Is there a way to perform this in Angular? -- Based on reading the ElementRef documentation, it seems like directly modifying the DOM in this way is not suggested.

HTML

```
<ul class="suggestions"></ul>
```

JavaScript

```
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions'); 
const html = places.map(place => {
const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
return `<li><span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span></li>`;
}).join('');

suggestions.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

using ngFor and binding [innerHTML]

HTML

```
<ul class="suggestions">
  <li *ngFor="let place of places" [innerHTML]="buildHTML(place)">
</ul>
```

JS

```
buildHTML(place) {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
  const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
  const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
  return `<li><span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span></li>`;
}
```